# Drawing a very large bit map

Tags: ios

I need to generate a very large bitmap that could be several times the size of my iPad screen. I want to find the best way of drawing it.

I can't simply draw the whole image in a single bitmap context, as that will consume too much memory. Is it possible to draw small chunks of the image in memory the append it to an existing image file? Or Am I better off generating several small image files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to tile your image in various resolutions that meet your needs.  [Here is a link](http://www.cimgf.com/2011/03/01/subduing-catiledlayer/) that describes CATiledLayer and how to implement it.

Comment: That sounds like a doable option. So basically I'm going to have to go with the latter option. Generate a number of small images (or draw slices on the fly) and let CATiled layer decide when a slice needs to load.

Comment: That's correct.  If your app supports zooming, you'll need to create additional tiles to support different levels.

Comment: Great. That's simpler than what I thought I was going to have to do. Thank you.

Comment: Adam you thanked the answer poster but didn't give him a +1 for doing so.